# XCode: Static Analyzer doesn't work if C/C++-Code used in project

Tags: iphone, xcode, clang, analyzer

with XCode 3.2.1 Apple delivered a built-in Clang static analyzer.
I am working on an iPhone project which uses some C-Code (one *.h* and *.c* file). When running *Build and Analyze*, Clang refuses work. The build results window just says *Build Succeeded*.

Any ideas how to get it running with C/C++-Code?

Regards,
Norbert

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clang does not analyze C++ code.  But it should work on C code compiled as C. How do you know it's not working? Or are you sure your C code has errors it should be catching?

Comment: I'm not that perfect ;) But seriously: a new line
    [UIView alloc];
doesn't generate a warning.
C++: Right, I checked out Clang's homepage.

Comment: ..and what did you find? I'm having the same issue. A project with c++ files. But analyzer won't find deliberate memory leaks anywhere, even in the top level objective C app delegate file.